# Is it possible to use DocIdRedir.aspx for linking to the display form

Tags: document-library, content-type

We are using a Link to a Document contenttype. The url used in this contenttype contains an url like http://ont/abc/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=N57YVKN5WQKX-2-2247. When testing this url it always opens the attachment of the item. Is it possible to use this way open the display form with the properties instead.

Comment: After pasting a persistent URL to an Excel, Word or PowerPoint using the hyperlink shows DocIdRedir.aspx as title of file. Problem is coming only for .xls files. In the case of .doc & .ppt it's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know DocIdRedir.aspx [does not support that option](https://gist.github.com/601861) (which is a shame, as it could have been easily added) - I've read quite a lot of its code using reflector when doing some research on the Document ID feature. However, it should be very easy to achieve by writing a feature with a custom page that works similarly to DocIdRedir.aspx, but redirect to the display page instead of the document (in fact, you can add easily a query parameter to control that, so you have both options).

See also:

- [`DocumentId.FindUrlsById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentid.findurlsbyid.aspx) - API method to find URLs by document ID.
- [`DocumentId.FindUrlById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentid.findurlbyid.aspx) - API method to get a link to one version of a file. It has somewhat poor error handling, so you probably want to change parts of [its source code](https://gist.github.com/601848), and of course redirect to the item's display form.
- [Using Document Id to Link to a Specific Version](http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/sharepoint-2010-using-document-id-to-link-to-a-specific-version/) - An implementation of a very similar handler - an alternative to DocIdRedir.aspx (from my blog)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the link you want to change is in a listview. If so and you want a link to the edit form instead of the document, the easiest thing to do is modify the view on the document library. Hide the `Document ID (linked to document)` column and add the `Edit (link to edit item)` column.

If instead, you are constructing the link yourself elsewhere in your site, change it to use: http://ont/abc/your-document-library/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID={Id} Note: in this case you should use the ID field (1,2,3,etc.) in the query parameter, not the Document ID